# Javascript/HTML button click error

Tags: javascript, html, button, assign

I am using JavaScript with my html page to try an get a button to show a message to the user, but when I click the button, nothing happens. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
<input type="button" name="get" id="getmsg" value="Get Message"/>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("getmsg").onclick = msgtouser;
    function (msgtouser)
    {
         var msg = "";
         var topick = "012345";
         for(var i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
         {
            msg += topick[Math.floor((Math.random()*topick.length)+1)];
         }
         alert(msg);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you define a function

```
function (msgtouser)
```

should be

```
function msgtouser ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try on this way:

```
    
        document.getElementById("getmsg").onclick = msgtouser;

        function msgtouser()
        {
            var msg = "";
            var topick = "012345";
            for(var i = 0; i << 8; ++i)
            {
                msg += topick[Math.floor((Math.random()*topick.length)+1)];
            }
        alert(msg);
        }
```

Note `function msgtouser()` instead `function (msgtouser)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the points which you need to correct:

- function (msgtouser) should be function msgtouser ()
- Use `window.load` or `.ready()` function.
- My guess is you are trying to generate random number between `1` and `012345` i.e `topick.length`,if so then remove that outer array `topick[]`.

Here is a working code:

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("getmsg").onclick = msgtouser;
    function msgtouser()
    {
var msg = "";
var topick = "012345";
for(var i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
 {
   msg += Math.floor((Math.random()*topick.length)+1);
 }
 alert(msg);
    }

 }
```